# Can we using partition by window function for below query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a query like below.
 Can i use partition by window function instead of group by and union? i have to change the partnername and partner number. Also based on the partner number one of the group by field is changing. my temptable contains around 24million records. i am working on the performance improvement of this query. currently my storedprocedure is taking around 1 hour to get execute.

```
INSERT INTO #FinalResultTable      
 (     
  [F1],              
    [F2],   
    [F3],              
    [F4],                  
    [Partner #],  
    [Partner Name],          
    [F5],              
    [F6],    
    [F7],              
    [F8],                
    [Partner Amount (rounded)]    
    ,[Entity Name]
    ,[Investment Number]
    )      

 SELECT   
    [F1],              
    [F2],   
    [F3],              
    [F4],                  
    -2 as [Partner #],      
 'Work Paper Total' 
    AS [PartnerName],   -- VARCHAR  
    [F5],              
    [F6],    
    [F7],              
    [F8],     
   MAX([WorkPaperTotal]) 
    , [Entity Name]
    ,[Investment Number]
  FROM #FinalResultTable   
  WHERE [Partner #] > 0   
 GROUP BY       
   [F1],              
    [F2],   
    [F3],              
    [F4],   
   [F5],              
    [F6],    
    [F7],              
    [F8], 
    [Entity Name],
    [Investment Number]                

     union all
     SELECT         


    [F1],              
    [F2],   
    [F3],              
    [F4],                 
  -3 as  [Partner #],      

       'Partner Total' 
     AS [PartnerName],   -- VARCHAR  
     [F5],              
    [F6],    
    [F9],              
    [F10],         

  MAX([WorkPaperTotal]) -SUM([Partner Amount (rounded)]) 

    , [Entity Name]
    ,[Investment Number]
  FROM #FinalResultTable   
  WHERE [Partner #] > 0   
 GROUP BY       
    [F1],              
    [F2],   
    [F3],              
    [F4],   
   [F5],              
    [F6],    
    [F9],              
    [F10], 
    [Entity Name],
    [Investment Number]
```

---

please give your suggestion to improve the performance of this query.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Comment: You are actually duplicating data in order to get the different sums. I.e. a #FinalResultTable row goes into both aggregations and the aggregations group by different columns. So no, you need `UNION ALL` and you need aggregation. You cannot change the query and still get the same result.

Comment: Consider in-memory tables and/or columnstore indexes if you're going to do a lot of this kind of aggregating on temp data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff we do have 3 different types of partners. partner numbers will be -1,-2 and -3.based on this partner number the calculation for partner amount will be different.Also partner name will be different.Before it was using a while loop. but it was taking more time since it do have 3 different inserts. i tried to remove it with union all. it improved the performance little bit. still not much. i am working on the performance improvement. but i am pretty new to database side.there is 24 miliion records. its taking 1.5 hrs now.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner how can we do it? Sorry as mentioned in the above comment i am kind of new to database side. before it was using a while loop which will insert data three times. but data insertion was taking time. so i thought of avoiding it by using single insert.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i dont have idea on in-memory table and columnstore index i will search for it. if you have any example could you please share

Answer (score 0):

I'm simplifying the request. You have data like this:

```
F1 | F7 | F9 | WorkPaperTotal | PartnerAmount
---+----+----+----------------+--------------
1  | 1  | 1  |           1000 |            10
1  | 1  | 2  |           2000 |            20
1  | 2  | 1  |           3000 |            30
1  | 2  | 2  |           4000 |            40
2  | 1  | 1  |           5000 |            50
```

And you want a result for

```
select f1, f7 as f, max(workpapertotal) as result, -2 as partner
from mytable
group by f1, f7
union all
select f1, f9 as f, max(workpapertotal) - sum(partneramount) as result, -3 as partner
from mytable
group by f1, f9;
```

The first part gives you:

```
F1 | F | result | partner
---+---+--------+--------
1  | 1 |   2000 |      -2
1  | 2 |   4000 |      -2
2  | 1 |   5000 |      -2
```

The second part gives you:

```
F1 | F | result | partner
---+---+--------+--------
1  | 1 |   2960 |      -3
1  | 2 |   3940 |      -3
2  | 1 |   4950 |      -3
```

Which make a final result of

```
F1 | F | result | partner
---+---+--------+--------
1  | 1 |   2000 |      -2
1  | 1 |   2960 |      -3
1  | 2 |   4000 |      -2
1  | 2 |   3940 |      -3
2  | 1 |   5000 |      -2
2  | 1 |   4950 |      -3
```

(where F means F7 for partner -2 and F9 for partner -3). From five rows in the table you get six result rows in spite of aggregation. So the aproach you are already taking to have two queries unioned is already the only feasible approach. I suppose your where clause (`WHERE [Partner #] > 0`) doesn't exclude very many rows, so most of the table's data must be read and sorted and then grouped in order to get aggregated. And this must even happen twice. That takes time. There is not much you can do about this. Buy hardware would be my first idea.

You may try the following indexes so as to provide pre-sorted data. It's an offer to the DBMS it may or may not accept for the query.

```
CREATE INDEX idx1
ON #FinalResultTable(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,[Entity Name],[Investment Number])
WHERE [Partner #] > 0;

CREATE INDEX idx2 
ON #FinalResultTable(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f9,f10,[Entity Name],[Investment Number])
WHERE [Partner #] > 0;
```